# Google maps API v3, Multiple custom markers, with different info windows

Tags: javascript

I have been bashing my head over the code here,
http://www.michiganwxsystem.com/tropics/active.html

```
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(19.09, -99.09);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 3,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("trop_canvas"), myOptions);

var invest = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://images.michiganwxsystem.com/symbols/invest.png",
new google.maps.Size(19, 22),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(9, 11));

var tdimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://images.michiganwxsystem.com/symbols/td.png",
new google.maps.Size(19, 22),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(9, 11));

var tsimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://images.michiganwxsystem.com/symbols/ts.png",
new google.maps.Size(19, 22),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(9, 11));

var h1image =  new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://images.michiganwxsystem.com/symbols/h1.png",
new google.maps.Size(19, 22),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(9, 11));
var h2image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://images.michiganwxsystem.com/symbols/h2.png",
new google.maps.Size(19, 22),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(9, 11));
var h3image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://images.michiganwxsystem.com/symbols/h3.png",
new google.maps.Size(19, 22),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(9, 11));
var h4image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://images.michiganwxsystem.com/symbols/h4.png",
new google.maps.Size(19, 22),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(9, 11));
var h5image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://images.michiganwxsystem.com/symbols/h5.png",
new google.maps.Size(19, 22),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(9, 11));



var all = [[ "Tropical Storm Alberto","9", "2100 UTC MON MAY 21 2012", "1006","EAST","7","34.8", "30.5","-77.9","tsimage"],
[ "Tropical Depression Two-e","4", "2100 UTC MON MAY 21 2012", "1005","WESTNORTHWEST","5.2","30.4", "9.6","-101.0","tdimage"],
[ "Tropical Storm Three","3", "2100 GMT MON MAY 21 2012", "N/A","NORTHWEST","8","35", "12.4","144.4","tsimage"],
 ];
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
 function infoCallback(infowindow, marker) { 
      return function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    }
  function setMarkers(map, all) {   
      for  (var i in all) {                                             
        var name    = all[i][0];
        var adv = all[i][1];
        var advdate     = all[i][2];
        var press   = all[i][3];
        var mvt     = all[i][4];
        var speed   = all[i][5];
        var maxwind     = all[i][6];
        var lat  = all[i][7];
        var lng = all[i][8];
        var mapicon = all[i][9];
        var latlngset;
        latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlngset,
    map: map,
    icon:  mapicon ,
    draggable: false,
    });


        var content = '<div class="info"> ' + name + 
'<div style="text-align:left; font-size:.77em;">Adv# ' + adv + ' Date ' + advdate + '<br />' +
'Pressure: ' + press + '<br />' +
'Movement: ' + mvt + ' @ ' + speed + '<br />' +
'Winds: ' + maxwind + ' </div></div>';      


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          infowindow.setContent(content);
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',infoCallback(infowindow, marker)
          );
      }
    }

    // Set all markers in the all variable
    setMarkers(map, all);
   };





     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

anybody have any idea's, 
If I remove the custom icon, and use the default push pin it works,
but that's not what I'm looking for ..

Answer (score 1):

If you debug your program by inserting a temporary `console.info( mapicon );` in your loop, you'll see that the `mapicon` variable is a **string** (having values of "tsimage", "tdimage" and "tsimage").  In other words, mapicon is **not** a variable of the type google.maps.MarkerImage but it should be.

Alter your `var all` variable and change "tsimage" into tsimage (remove quotes, so it's not a string), so it points to your previous variable. Something (reduced version) like this:

```
var all = [
    [
        "Tropical Storm Alberto"
        ...
        "30.5",
        "-77.9",
        tsimage
    ],
...
```

See this jsfiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RjDDg/

Comment: Also, sorry, I always assume web developers use Firefox with firebug. Or at least Chrome, since they have debug console functions.